# Is it possible to find logback log files programmatically?

Tags: java, logging, logback

It would be useful to automatically attach log files to support emails. I could set the path programmatically (as in [Setting Logback Appender path programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803184/setting-logback-appender-path-programmatically)), but I'd prefer to let users configure logging in the familiar way via `logback.xml`. So, can I find the files logback uses for logging?

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand the question. Could you expand a bit?

Comment: @Ceki: more generally, can I get a list of all appenders used by Logback?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get the list of all appenders in a certain context.  To do this:

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
for (Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
        for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders(); index.hasNext();) {
            Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();
        }
    }
```

This iterates over the list of all appenders in all loggers for the current context.

Comment: iteratorForAppenders method doesn't exist any more on logger (http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html). Any idea how it works now?

Comment: @user3885927 make sure you're importing ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger and not org.slf4j.Logger !

Answer (score 24):

Answer given by @tafoo85 is correct one but it will give you appenders only.

To more specific get file used by Logback logger i hope below code will help some one.

```
File clientLogFile;
FileAppender<?> fileAppender = null;
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
for (Logger logger : context.getLoggerList())
{
     for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders();
                 index.hasNext();)
     {
           Object enumElement = index.next();
           if (enumElement instanceof FileAppender) {
                fileAppender=(FileAppender<?>)enumElement;
           }
     }
}

if (fileAppender != null) {
     clientLogFile=new File(fileAppender.getFile());
}
else {
     clientLogFile = null;
}

Log.d("logfile path", clientLogFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Was exactly what I needed, though I changed the line `Object enumElement = index.next();` to `Appender<ILoggingEvent> enumElement= index.next();` as well as `fileAppender = (FileAppender<?>) enumElement;` to `fileAppender = (FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>) enumElement;` to make it work for me.

Comment: @danial that will be more specific. but if you want 2-3 file logger (debug and trace) then this code will work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the actual file like so:

```
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

    for (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
        for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders(); index.hasNext();) {
            Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();

            if (appender instanceof FileAppender) {
                FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fa = (FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>)appender;
                ResilientFileOutputStream rfos = (ResilientFileOutputStream)fa.getOutputStream();
                File file = rfos.getFile();

                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```