# Can i use Dynamic variable(like time) to construct static final variable(constant)

Tags: java, android, exception, constants, static-variables

For building File name i'm constructing name like below mentioned way

```
public static final String JSON_LOG_FILE_NAME = "JSON"
  +getUserName() + System.currentTimeMillis()
  + ".txt";
```

this is working till yesterday and now it is giving exceptioninintializationerror.
And my doubt is can use dynamic values like android device time and database values as a part of static final variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to use ***final*** when you want it to be modified based on time.

You can create a final variable like "JSON" and you can use concatenation to name the file.

FOR YOUR CASE: The above logic is valid i.e The file name changes only when the class is loaded and not every time you use the variable. The value is constant and you wont find the value of time changing dynamically when ever you use it.

Comment: You have an edit rejected. If you want to change code in an answer, check the profile of the user. If they are currently around, make a comment. If they haven't been here a long time, go for the edit, and mention that in the edit comment. If it gets rejected, leave a comment on the answer with the suggestion. If you get to 2,000 reputation, you can make those types of edit without review.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` to generate file on time bases.

Here is the complete example. Hope this helps you

[Logback - set log file name programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824620/logback-set-log-file-name-programatically)

Comment: it is not just about time but getUsername() method which retrieves from Db also.am i using in a right way?