# Configuring logback to log to log file with dynamic name

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have the following problem.

Say I have one point of logging in my application. For example I'm receiving some request strings like:

```
[ABC] 123...
```

I want to log requests in the following way:

```
[ABC] 123 ... // -> abc.log
[XYZ] 567 ... // -> xyz.log
...
```

So log file name can be any combination of 3 [A-Z] symbols.

How can I achieve that with logback?

Comment: Maybe this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2489569

Comment: @smsnheck It doesn't help at all. Because it describes logging for two concrete files. I can't define 27x27x27 appenders for each combination of A-Z symbols.

Comment: Ok, I see. What about variable replacement with <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">    <file>${logFileName}</file> </appender> for the XML config and loggerContext.putProperty("logFileName", "someFileName"); in Java?

Comment: You really understood the problem. But trying to do that I have the following:     LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    loggerContext.putProperty("logFileName", "hello");
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("hello");
    logger.info("hello");
and this file is created - logFileName_IS_UNDEFINED.log . It seems I don't know the proper way to pass variable to the context.

Comment: How does your XML config look like?

Comment: @smsnheck I've succeed solving my problem using - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824620/logback-set-log-file-name-programatically . Thank you very much!