# Android Google Maps onMapReady store GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

i have an android app in development, which uses this google maps api v2. To get an instance of the google map im using the [onMapReady callback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)).
In this callback i get an instance of the google map, can i store this instace local an reuse it, without getting a new one every time i have to update the map? Or is there any issue with reusing this instance over time? I just like to get sure that there is nothing with which i could get into problem.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can store an instance of the Google Map reference, and re-use it just as you would if you called `getMap()` instead of `getMapAsync()`.

Just make sure to re-call `getMapAsync()` from `onResume()` if needed, since often the map reference will become null after `onPause()` is called.

Here is a simple example to illustrate.  This code places a Marker each time the user taps the map, something you need a valid map reference to do.  There is also a button that calls `startActivityForResult()` and launches another Activity.

Here is the code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marker;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, 100);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 100) {
            Log.d("MyMap", "onActivityResult " + data.getStringExtra("result"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d("MyMap", "onPause");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.d("MyMap", "onResume");
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {

            Log.d("MyMap", "setUpMapIfNeeded");
            ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("MyMap", "onMapReady");
        mMap = googleMap;
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);


        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                Log.d("MyMap", "MapClick");

                //remove previously placed Marker
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                //place marker where user just clicked
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

                Log.d("MyMap", "MapClick After Add Marker");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here are the resulting logs from running the app, tapping it once to place a Marker, then clicking the button to launch the second Activity, returning back to the map Activity, and then tapping the map again to place Markers.

You can see that when `onPause()` was called after the button click launches the other Activity, the map reference was lost, as when `onResume()` was called, it made another call to `getMapAsync()`.  However, it's all fine, because the code is set up to take this into account.

```
 D/MyMap﹕ onResume
 D/MyMap﹕ setUpMapIfNeeded
 D/MyMap﹕ onMapReady
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick After Add Marker
 D/MyMap﹕ onPause
 D/MyMap﹕ onActivityResult ok
 D/MyMap﹕ onResume
 D/MyMap﹕ setUpMapIfNeeded
 D/MyMap﹕ onMapReady
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick After Add Marker
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick After Add Marker
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick After Add Marker
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick After Add Marker
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick After Add Marker
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick
 D/MyMap﹕ MapClick After Add Marker
```