# is suitable to use OnMapReady() more than once in android Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have this doubt because somebody told me onMapReady() only must to be called once in an Activity. 
I know the way to call this methos is:

```
         map.getMapAsync(this);
```

but I want to optimize my code.

Comment: `OnMapReady()` gets called by the API, not your code... And yes it's called only once. And why would you need to call it "more than once" "to optimize" your code?

Comment: well, I was calling this method every time I wanted to reposition a marker, but I didn't know if this practice was reliable

Comment: Don't do that.  If you have code that you want run at startup, and also to update Marker positions, put that in a separate method.  Then, call that method from `onMapReady()`, and also when you want to reposition Markers.  The important part to have in `onMapReady()` is to set your reference to the Map that is returned, and you don't want to do that more than once.

Comment: @DanielNugent then, onMapReady() is a listener or is a method to initialize?

Comment: It's a callback method for an Interface. Take a look at the code structure in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31328143/android-google-maps-onmapready-store-googlemap/31329182#31329182  Note in that example you would only want to call `setUpMap()` one time, but it's just to give you an idea of how your code structure should be.