# How to add a FIleHandler to a HttpServlet ( java.util.logging)

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I have implemented a `HttpServlet` that uses `java.util.logging` for leaving Log.
Now I want that the Servlet leaves the Log inside a txt file.

I know the `FileHandler`s implements this functionality.
Doubts:

- Where I have to put the code that adds the `FileHanlder` to the Logger? by "where", I mean in which part of the code. I think that in the `service()` method is not correct at all.

  ```
   @Override
   protected void service(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            //  HERE???
    }
  ```
- I want that the `FileHandler` is instanced only one time , so I have no locks problem with the txt file. How can I do that? Do you have any samples of code/recommendations?

Please forgive my bad explanation, but I am lost, and very noob in Java.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960099/how-to-set-up-java-logging-using-a-properties-file-java-util-logging

Comment: ¿What about the place to add the implementation inside the Servlet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227292/setting-java-util-logging-destination-programmatically

Comment: If i place the FileHandler code inside service, a lot of log files are created. I just add:  FileHandler fileTxt = new FileHandler(logDirectory+"/RetrieveServiceLog.txt",true);